# Why is my brute force solution faster than the optimized hashtable solution?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, dictionary, hashtable

here are two solutions I submitted for the [Two Sum problem on leetcode](https://leetcode.com/problems/two-sum/) in Python3:

**Brute force: O(n^2)**

Runtime: 44 ms

Memory Usage: 14.4 MB

```
class Solution:
    def twoSum(self, nums: List[int], target: int) -> List[int]:
        for indx1, val1 in enumerate(nums):
            for indx2, val2 in enumerate(nums[indx1+1:]):
                if val1 + val2 == target:
                    return [indx1, indx2+indx1+1]
        return []
```

**Hashtable (dict) solution: O(n)**

Runtime: 52 ms

Memory Usage: 14.3 MB

```
class Solution:
    def twoSum(self, nums: List[int], target: int) -> List[int]:
        h = {}
        for i, num in enumerate(nums):
            n = target - num
            if n not in h:
                h[num] = i
            else:
                return [h[n], i]
```

I really can't understand why the brute force O(n^2) is faster than the optimized O(n) solution??!

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Do you know the input data submitted to your code?

If the data size is small, the brute force solution might be better than optimized hashtable solution.

Comment: @Brian No I don't have much idea about the input data, but why is a smaller data size supposed to give faster results with the brute force solution?

Comment: Run time measures at leetcode are not conclusive or consistent (rerunning the same code several times, won't guarantee same results). There are many things that can influence that timing, including the amount of resources used on that server at the moment of testing. That is why the big O notation is used to provide a better asymptotic upper bound. When your input data will increase eventually the optimized result will be better.

Comment: Okay I see thank you @Thymen.